# Db2 table creation issue due to page size

Tags: db2

in DB2 LUW version 11.x, My pagesize for the db instance in 8k.

I am trying to create table with datatype length varchar(32000).

It throws me the error DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-670, SQLSTATE=54010, SQLERRMC=32677;;65813

Do i need to increase page size or any other db configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [extended_row_sz](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=parameters-extended-row-sz-extended-row-size) database parameter to allow creation of such a table in your current tablespace.

```
SELECT VALUE FROM SYSIBMADM.DBCFG WHERE NAME = 'extended_row_sz';

|VALUE |
|------|
|ENABLE|

SELECT PAGESIZE FROM SYSCAT.TABLESPACES WHERE TBSPACE='USERSPACE1';

|PAGESIZE|
|--------|
|8192    |

CREATE TABLE TEST_EXTROW (I INT, C VARCHAR(32000)) IN USERSPACE1;
INSERT INTO TEST_EXTROW (I, C) VALUES (1, 'short'), (2, repeat('long', 7000));
SELECT LENGTH(C) LEN FROM TEST_EXTROW;

|LEN  |
|-----|
|5    |
|28000|
```

Comment: Mark Barinstein- Godfather of DB2

Answer (score 0):

There is no pagesize defined on instance level. The database itself has a default pagesize but the pagesize can be set / overwritten on tablespace level.

Check out [CREATE TABLESPACE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-tablespace) and use the corresponding PAGESIZE (pagesize 32K) and create a new tablespace and bufferpool for your table.

Comment: no. It just means that your database does not yet have a tablespace (and matching bufferpool) whose pagesize is 32KB. This is normal.  Create those 2 objects (bufferpool and tablespace), then create your new table in the new tablespace.

Comment: Can I extend the EXTENTSIZE parameter? Currently it is 4. Will it work?

Comment: @mao - in the lower environment. My pagesize is 4k and EXTENT SIZE is 32 still this tables is created there

Comment: Then the working environment __either__ already has relevant sized tablespaces/bufferpools __OR__ is configured with `extended_row_sz` already as per Mark Barinstein's answer.  The `extent size` is not relevant.